# Where can I find these SATA cables for ASUS ROG - AS G20AJ 1A I74790?

Tags: sata, cable

I am desperately looking for these two data cables for my ASUS ROG system and I am not able to find them anywhere. Online or Offline.

Model Number - https://ibb.co/j5r0hzb - AS G20AJ 1A I74790/S8G/1BA/A

[image]

Cable 1 - SATA Power Cable - https://ibb.co/4tKdzKQ
Both ends are Female

END 1 - This has 15 pins -> https://ibb.co/k2mGrHr

END 2 - This has 4 pins ->https://ibb.co/sg2Zv3L
[image]

Cable 2 - SATA Data Cable - https://ibb.co/k1pWsWr - Both ends are right angle

[image]

Can anyone please guide me to where I can get them?

Answer (score 0):

Cable 1: That doesn't look like a SATA data cable, thats SATA power and which one it is depends on your PSU

Cable 2: You can grab any SATA data cable to replace that one, like this one from bol.com: https://www.bol.com/be/nl/p/ninzer-premium-sata-iii-data-kabel-high-speed-63-cm/9200000073543948/?bltgh=jucIoGyGYlOKjOpTRdJJqg.4_39.40.ProductTitle

Comment: Yes, It is mentioned in the question. It is a SATA power cable. I am specifically looking for the one with Dupont connector.

Comment: hmm, , i dont know that connector...